# iOS - send exceptions to Google Analytics

Tags: ios, google-analytics

I'm trying to send exceptions to GA, but something confuses me.

According to the header file:

```
+ (GAIDictionaryBuilder *)createExceptionWithDescription:(NSString *)description
                                               withFatal:(NSNumber *)fatal;
```

But in the [DEV guide example](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/exceptions):

```
[tracker send:[GAIDictionaryBuilder
    createExceptionWithDescription:@"Connection timout %d: %@", connectionError, errorDescription  // Exception description. May be truncated to 100 chars.
                         withFatal:NO] build];  // isFatal (required). NO indicates non-fatal exception.
```

One is `NSNumber` and one is `BOOL` for `fatal`. So, what number should I fill in for `fatal`? Or simply 1 or 0 to represent YES or NO? Since a boolean seems to make more sense to me.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this..

```
[tracker send:[GAIDictionaryBuilder
    createExceptionWithDescription:@"Connection timout %d: %@", connectionError, errorDescription  // Exception description. May be truncated to 100 chars.
                         withFatal:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO] build];
```

Comment: or use the shorthand @NO

Answer (score 0):

```
[tracker send:[[GAIDictionaryBuilder
createExceptionWithDescription:@"Connection timout %d: %@", connectionError, errorDescription
withFatal:NO]build]];
```